# Force audio to high quality output

Tags: audio, pulseaudio, displayport

I'm running CentOS 7 with pulseaudio.  Due to a bug in my monitor firmware, I must send audio over the displayport audio as 24 or 32 bit (not 16bit which causes audio failure on the monitor).

How can I tell what audio resolution is currently in use by Linux?  And how can I force it to 24/32 bit?

Answer (score 0):

Can't think of a simple way to do it.

I'd try to use `hw` or `slave` [ALSA plugin](http://www.alsa-project.org/alsa-doc/alsa-lib/pcm_plugins.html) for force the format to 24/32 bit. Test that first directly with ALSA, with Pulseaudio stopped (`pasuspender` etc., `aplay -D`). Then use the `module-alsa-sink` [Pulseaudio module](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/Modules/#index4h3) to create a Pulseaudio sink for it (`pacmd load-module`). You may have to modify the `module-udev-detect` call in `/etc/pulse` to ignore the old ALSA hardware, if this doesn't happen automatically.

(Very general advice, I'd have to try it out myself for a step-by-step description).

`pacmd list-sinks` and `pacmd list-sink-inputs` have a `sample spec` field that designates bitwidth used, but I am not sure how accurate that is given the various conversions at various places involved.

Answer (score 0):

> And how can I force it to 24/32 bit?

In `/etc/pulse/daemon.conf` set

```
default-sample-format = s24ne
```